# cant get id value in to the html form

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update the table in DB and every row (result) has its own update button which is a form. When i click the button nothing happens because I don't know how to transfer value of id to a form and then to a UPDATE query.

```
 while(list($naziv,$tvrtka_id)=mysqli_fetch_row($resultA))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$naziv."</td>";
    echo "<td>"?> 
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $tvrtka_id; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="odobriZahtjev" value="Odobri zahtjev"> 
    </form> <?php "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
} //this is from a if statment which creates table
if(isset($_POST['odobriZahtjev']))
   {
     $firmId = $_POST['id'];
     $updateAnswers = "UPDATE tvrtka 
     SET zahtjev = '0', preostaliOdgovori=preostaliOdgovori + 10
     WHERE tvrtka.tvrtka_id='$firmId'";
     $result=queryDB($connect,$updateAnswers);
  }
```

When button is clicked the value of a request for answers is set to 0 and 10 answers are added to company.
tvrtka_id is the id which is supposed to go to a UPDATE query.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a PHP var inside HTML you have to print it to the HTML (using `echo` in your case).

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $tvrtka_id; ?>">
```

This will probably solve the problem with your update query when the form is submitted too

Comment: Will get back to you with the results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked perfectly except i had to put it like this: 
`"<?php echo "$tvrtka_id"; ?>">` and use `header();` after the UPDATE query.